# Rails ActiveRecord Find with Date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a hard time figuring this out but how do I tell my finder statement to ignore the time of the Datetime field in the db?

```
def trips_leaving_in_two_weeks
  Trip.find(:all, :conditions => ["depart_date = ?", 2.weeks.from_now.to_date])
end
```

I want depart_date to come back as just a date but it keeps returning the time as well and causing this equality not to work. Is there someway to just compare against the dates? Thanks

### Edit

Here's the code I'm using now that works:

```
Trip.find(:all, :conditions => ["DATE(depart_date) = ?", 2.weeks.from_now.to_date])
```

Comment: depart_date is a date or a datetime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure which DB you're using but does this work?

```
"depart_date = DATE(?)"
```

Comment: No, it's still returning nothing. The 2.weeks.from_now.to_date is getting passed in fine it's just that the depart_date in the comparison is returning as a datetime. So right now it's comparing a date to a datetime object. Thanks though

Comment: Actually I switched the DATE() method around the depart_date and that worked! You get the accepted answer for getting me on the right path. :) Thanks

Comment: Try it the other way around: `"DATE(depart_date) = ?", 2.weeks.from_now.to_date` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I would use this approach:

**Rails 3.x**

```
Trip.where(
  :depart_date => 2.weeks.from_now.beginning_of_day..2.weeks.from_now.end_of_day
)
```

**Rails 2.x**

```
Trip.all(
:conditions => {
  :depart_date => 2.weeks.from_now.beginning_of_day..2.weeks.from_now.end_of_day
})
```

If you index the `depart_date` column this solution will be efficient as the query uses the index. This solution is DB neutral.

When calculated fields are used in a where clause, the performance degrades(unless there is a special index).